# Ffmpeg uncompressed raw video with timestamps?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to find a video format supported by ffmpeg that consists of a stream of uncompressed yuv444 frames with attached timestamps. My use case is that I want to do image processing with a custom program, but my video doesn't have consistent timestamps, so I  need to preserve them. As in I want to run a shell pipe like:

ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v ? -pixfmt yuv444 -o - | myfilter | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -c:v ? -o out.mp4

Where myfilter reads fixed size frames from stdin in a format like [header][yuv444 data], processes them and writes them to stdout with the same header, preserving the frame timestamp.

Edit: fixed size frames and no compression are not hard requirements as long as each frame is freestanding and reading and writing them is trivial.

Comment: Can't think of a direct solution now, but you can export rawvideo with no headers, process them and then adapt the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28086775/5726027) when reconstituting the video.